# Dynamically Add ASP Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

How do you dynamically add an **asp taged control** to a form on asp.net C# code behind? I am trying to do something similar to the following, but specifically where the string can change from Button to Textbox if needed.

```
string control1 = "asp:button";
HtmlGenericControl xControl = new HtmlGenericControl(control1);
body1.Controls.Add(xControl);
```

Is there a way to do this on a ASP.Net webform? I have tried the HtmlGenericControl but this is obviously not going to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, you cannot add dynamic ASP controls, But you can add HTML controls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding ASP.Net Controls Dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799636/adding-asp-net-controls-dynamically)

Comment: Getting dynamically added controls to behave as expected in Webforms is challenging. If you need to show either a text box or a static text, it's easier to add both the textbox and the label/literal control to the `.aspx` file and then hide one of them in the code behind page...

Answer (score 2):

You can by adding div runat server
c# code

```
 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.Text = "test";
 maindiv.Controls.Add(btn);
```

html

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" id="maindiv">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx