# Newly added button doesn't work in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Web forms and not MVC here, And I'm having a difficult time finding a way to bind OnClick to newly generated buttons. I coded myself into a corner, my page's content gets added from its code behind with hml in string

```
articleHTML += "<asp:Button ID='button' type='button' OnClick='Pull_Click' class='btn btn-default btn- lg'>Pull</asp:button>";

protected void Pull_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
        LabelTest.Text = "Works";  
}
```

Pull_Cick doesn't get called when a button is clicked. I'm guessing I need to loop through my content directly in the template? Thanks!

Comment: `asp:Button` requires a `runat` tag

Comment: You  can't create a server side Button control via JavaScript. Think about how Web Forms works. The Web Forms markup is processed on the server side, the resulting HTML is sent to the client. There is no mechanism on the client to convert ASP controls to HTML and wire them up correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are adding the button is not correct Please check

[Dynamically Add ASP Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905143/dynamically-add-asp-controls/40905219#40905219)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

for on click event

```
 Button btn = new Button();
 btn.Text = "test";
 btn.Click += btn_Click;   
 maindiv.Controls.Add(btn);

 void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

to make button call ajax

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "test";
        btn.OnClientClick = "newbtn_Click()";


    [WebMethod]
    public static string newbtnSubmit(string name)
    {
        return name;
    }
```

and in JavaScript add

```
 <script>
    function newbtn_Click()
    {
        var dataValue = { "name": "my name"};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/newbtnSubmit",
            data: dataValue,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
                alert("complete: " + status + "\n\nResponse: " + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Why is it not correct? I don't want to go somewhere and read why it is not correct. If you think it is not correct then add the reason to your answer here.

Comment: because you can't add the asp button as string html at run time.
I added the reference from msdn in my answear

Comment: So now how do i make my button call ajax? Thanks

Comment: @JamesA I edited the answer for you to make ajax call