# Add ASP.NET controls dynamically to a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-web-api

I am fairly new to web development and my goal is to add a label and textbox control, or drop down dynamically to a page, without re-programming the page and re-publishing the app. As an example, via the admin module I have the ability to add or remove a field to an input page in the application. For example, this input page would have 4 fields, but a new requirement requires me to add a 5th field, be it a drop down list, label with an associated text box, checkbox, etc.

I have googled and found this link: [Adding ASP.Net Controls Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799636/adding-asp-net-controls-dynamically), which is a start.

It seems from what I found that I would need to generate this through an application function, ex. CreateTextBoxControl(....) and have either placeholders on the page or some other way.

My preference would be MVC using a Restful WEB API with SQL Server stored procedures.

I will continue to research this, but any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: please review this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563426/how-to-dynamically-create-asp-net-controls-within-dynamically-created-asp-net-co

Answer (score 0):

**Create the Dynamic Control and Hook It Up**

1. In Solution Explorer, click Show All Files to display a list of the files that are associated with WebForm1.aspx. Open the WebForm1.aspx.cs file.
2. Declare the TextBox controls in the .cs (code-behind) file. Also, declare a variable for the existing form element in the .aspx file. Update the declarations following the declaration for the WebForm1 class:

   public class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label1;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label2;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label3;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label4;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Button1;

   // Added by hand for access to the form.
   protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm Form1;

   // Added by hand; will create instance in OnInit.
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox1;
   protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox2;

> The TextBox declarations are entered by hand as they would be if a
>   TextBox were dragged from the toolbox to the .aspx page. However, in
>   this case, you create the controls dynamically.

3. Add code to create the TextBox controls dynamically. The controls are created every time that the page is run. The best place to do this is in the OnInit function that the WebForm1 class provides.

> Locate the OnInit function. Expand the code that is marked with the
>   "Web Form Designer generated code" comment. Modify the OnInit function
>   so that it looks similar to the following code:

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    // Create dynamic controls here.
    // Use "using System.Web.UI.WebControls;"
    TextBox1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox1.ID = "TextBox1";
    TextBox1.Style["Position"] = "Absolute";
    TextBox1.Style["Top"] = "25px";
    TextBox1.Style["Left"] = "100px";
    Form1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);

    TextBox2 = new TextBox();
    TextBox2.ID = "TextBox2";
    TextBox2.Style["Position"] = "Absolute";
    TextBox2.Style["Top"] = "60px";
    TextBox2.Style["Left"] = "100px";
    Form1.Controls.Add(TextBox2);

    this.TextBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_TextChanged);
    this.TextBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_TextChanged);

    // 
    // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
    // 
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

> This code dynamically creates two TextBox controls, sets their IDs and
>   positions, and then binds them to the Form Controls collection. The
>   code also wires up the TextChanged events of the text boxes to a
>   handler (TextBox_TextChanged).
>
> Other than setting the TextBox position programmatically and binding
>   it to the Form Controls collection, you can add Web Forms Panel
>   controls to the .aspx page and bind the text boxes to those in the
>   OnInit function, similar to this:

```
TextBox1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox1.ID = "TextBox1";
//Form1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(TextBox1);
```

> Note When you create dynamic controls on a Web Form, the controls must
>   be created and added to the controls collection either in the OnInit
>   or in the Page_Load events. Otherwise, the controls behave
>   unexpectedly.

4. Initialize the Text property and styles for the text boxes. Modify the existing Page_Load function as follows:

   private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       if(!IsPostBack)
       {
           // Set the initial properties for the text boxes.
           TextBox1.Text = "TextBox1";
           TextBox2.Text = "TextBox2";
       }
   }

> The initial value of the text boxes (if(!IsPostBack)) is set one time.
>   This information is maintained by the IPostBackDataHandler interface
>   for the text boxes, making it unecessary to reset the value for
>   subsequent posts.

5. Provide a handler for the TextChanged events of the TextBox control. Add the following code after the Page_Load function body:

   private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       TextBox txtBoxSender = (TextBox)sender;
       string strTextBoxID = txtBoxSender.ID;

   ```
   switch(strTextBoxID)
   {
       case "TextBox1":
           Label3.Text = "TextBox1 text was changed";
           break;
       case "TextBox2":
           Label4.Text = "TextBox2 text was changed";
           break;
   }
   ```

   }

> This code checks to see which control triggered the event and then
>   reports this to the user by using the approprite Label control. Notice
>   that this function handles the TextChanged event for both of the
>   dynamically-created TextBox controls. By default, AutoPostBack is
>   false for the TextBox controls. Therefore, changing the text in the
>   controls does not cause a PostBack to the server. However, when the
>   Submitbutton is clicked to post the form to the server, the
>   TextChanged events for the TextBox controls are triggered, and this
>   function is called.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/317794/how-to-dynamically-create-controls-in-asp-net-by-using-visual-c-net